# How to remove data after space in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Let's suppose I have data like

```
column
ABC 
ABC PQR
ABC (B21)
XYZ ABC
```

and I wanted output as first string i.e.

```
ABC 
XYZ
```

i.e. group by column
but I could not able to remove string after space.

Comment: I've added "code markers" (```) to preserve your original formatting: please [edit] if the result is incorrect. Can you confirm that all the data you're interested in is in one column, and that you want to group-and-extract the portion of that column up to the first space of each value?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following would do what you want :-

```
SELECT * FROM mytable GROUP BY CASE WHEN instr(mycolumn,' ') > 0 THEN substr(mycolumn,1,instr(mycolumn,' ')-1) ELSE mycolumn END;
```

- obviously table and column name changed appropriately.

As an example, using your data plus other data to demonstrate, the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (mycolumn);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('ABC'),('ABC PQR'),('ABC (B21)'),('XYZ'),('A B'),('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA B'),(' ABC'),(' XZY');
SELECT * FROM mytable;
SELECT *,group_concat(mycolumn) FROM mytable GROUP BY CASE WHEN instr(mycolumn,' ') > 0 THEN substr(mycolumn,1,instr(mycolumn,' ')-1) ELSE mycolumn END;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
```

- group_concat added to show the columns included in each group

Produces:-

The ungrouped table (first SELECT):-

[image]

The grouped result (plus group_concat column) :-

[image]

- the first row being grouped due to the first character being a space in  `ABC` and  `XZY`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do any aggregation, so there is no need for a `GROUP BY` clause.
Use string functions like `SUBSTR()` and `INSTR()` to get the 1st word of each string and then use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates from the results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(columnname, 1, INSTR(columnname || ' ', ' ') - 1) new_column
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=339d12b5a741782756eaa055462500c1).
Results:

> | new_column |
> | --- |
> | ABC |
> | XYZ |